# Setting custom host in Nuxt config doesn't work

Tags: nuxt.js

Inside my `nuxt.config.js`, when I change the port, it's taken into account, but not the host:

```js
export default {
  server: {
    port: 8002, // default: 3000
    host: 'localhost2 // default: localhost
  }
  // other configs
}
```

In my `/etc/hosts`, I have:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost2
```

```
$ npm run dev
...
ℹ Listening on: http://localhost:8002/
...
```

What's wrong in my configuration?

Comment: i think change host like, host: '127.0.0.1' in config and as you already have mapped, you can access via localhost2 in browser.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to only occur with `@nuxt/cli` (as of v2.12.2). [When the hostname resolves to `127.0.0.1`, `@nuxt/server` automatically overrides it to be `localhost`.](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/1fda184/packages/server/src/listener.js#L48) It's possibly a bug, and I recommend reporting it in their [GitHub issues](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues).

A workaround is to use the `dev` NPM script generated from [`create-nuxt-app`](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app), which does not exhibit the problem above:

```js
"scripts": {
  "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server",
  "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server/index.js",
}
```

The commands above assume the following file exists:

```js
// server/index.js
const express = require('express')
const consola = require('consola')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
const app = express()

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
let config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')

async function start() {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  const {
    host = process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1',
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000
  } = nuxt.options.server

  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  }

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render)

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host)
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  })
}
start()
```